# Laravel Combine Separate Records Into One Record

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Hi guys I have 3 records which I want to merge into one json record. So for example I am doing this query:

```
$shopList = $inventory
->select('shop_code', 'barcode', 'product_code', 'matrix_level_code_1',
'matrix_level_code_2', 'matrix_level_code_3', 'qty')->get();
return response()->json($shopList);
```

It returns:

```
{
    "shop_code": "001",
    "barcode": "505455553989",
    "product_code": "ANXA-683B-V148",
    "matrix_level_code_1": "1Z",
    "matrix_level_code_2": "0",
    "matrix_level_code_3": "",
    "qty": 3
 }
```

But I want this to be displayed as:

```
{
   "shop_code": "001",
   "barcode": "505455553989",
   "sku": "ANXA-683B-V148-1Z-0",
   "qty": 3
}
```

Is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat` on mysql in order to combine more results into one and alias them with custom key.

```
$shopList = $inventory->select([
    'shop_code',
    'barcode',
    DB::raw('concat(product_code, "-", matrix_level_code_1, "-", matrix_level_code_2, "-", matrix_level_code_3) as sku'),
    'qty'
])->get();
```

Make sure you put `use DB;` at the top.

Comment: Thank you I would add concat_ws('-', matrix_level_code_3) for the last record but you gave me the idea!